# How can I define `LoneElement` and `Emptiness` for composed collections?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a case class which is a simple wrapper around a collection:

```
final case class Foo(foos: Seq[Int])
```

and in my tests, I'd like to make assertions about the emptiness and lone elements of `Foo#foos`. I'm currently circumventing the problem by accessing `Foo#foos` directly:

```
foo.foos shouldBe empty
```

or

```
foo.foos.loneElement should===(1)
```

This works, but breaks encapsulation.

I've looked through the scalatest docs, but haven't found a way to define these operators outside of a companion.

How can I define them? Bonus points for inlining them in the tests.

Comment: Is it really a `Seq[Int]`, and not some generic `Foo[A](foos: Seq[A])`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It's a specialized type, but my case class is not as dumb as above case class.

Comment: Something like `case class FooOne(elems: Seq[Int]) { def isEmpty() = this.elems.isEmpty }` could work?

Comment: @mfirry and `LoneElement`?

Comment: By "specialized" you mean "concrete, non-generic", and not "generic and @specialized". I think you are saying what I hope you are saying, just wanted to point out that calling a type "specialized" might be confusing because there is "@specialized" annotation for generics ;)

Comment: Ha, whoops. My mistake, @AndreyTyukin. I mean concrete. I haven't unlearned C++ yet.

Comment: @erip Don't unlearn it. It's definitely not something you would want to re-learn after learning Scala ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define some implicits to deal with `Foo` (in the `test`-directory, not in the `main` source code tree):

```
import org.scalatest.enablers.Emptiness

trait FooImplicits {

  case class FooLoneElementWrapper(wrapped: Foo) {
    def loneElement: Int = {
      assert(wrapped.foos.size == 1)
      wrapped.foos(0)
    }
  }
  implicit def fooCanHazLoneElement(foo: Foo) = FooLoneElementWrapper(foo)
  implicit object FooEmptiness extends Emptiness[Foo] {
    def isEmpty(foo: Foo) = foo.foos.isEmpty
  }

}
```

Now simply mixin the trait `FooImplicits` into the `FlatSpec` where you would like to use it:

```
import org.scalatest._

class FooSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with FooImplicits {

  "Foo" should "be empty when it's empty" in {
    Foo(Seq()) shouldBe empty
  }

  it should "have loneElements" in {
    val x = Foo(Seq(1))
    x.loneElement should equal (1)
  }
}
```

Profit:

```
[info] Foo
[info] - should be empty when it's empty
[info] - should have loneElements
```

Notice that the `FooImplicits` can be defined in the same `package` as `Foo` in the `main` tree, even though it is in a completely different `test`-source-code tree. This way, it can access package-visible members of `Foo`.

Comment: Excellent. Cheers!